# Python3 - How to randomly organize items in an array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

let's suppose I have an array

array = [A, B, C, D, E]
how can I randomize the order of the items in this array and put everything together into a string variable to print it.

Example of output:
CABDE

Comment: `array = [A, B, C, D, E]` isn't even valid Python since you haven't declared `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, or `E`.

Answer (score 2):

The word you're looking for is "shuffle"

```
import random
random.shuffle(array)
```